# Google coral board disconnects randomly

Tags: disconnect, google-coral

I connect to google coral development board using ubuntu terminal with `mdt shell` command which basically connects via ssh through USB (no wifi required). It has occurred many times that the board disconnects, or becomes unresponsive. Since it happens randomly, I do not know what triggers it and when it will happen, nor can I reproduce it. To confirm, I run `mdt devices` whenever it happens and it outputs nothing.

Has anyone faced this issue? If yes, what could be the reason and how to deal with it? It will be used for long time demonstration in a fair, so this is a big problem.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, are you running Ubuntu Terminal on Ubuntu OS or Windows running ubuntu terminal?
I had similar issues when I tried doing mdt devices but after I switched to Ubuntu OS, everything worked fine.
Second thing you can try is different cable, maybe the cable is having a lose connection
Let me know if this works.